# HREF link is duplicating PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I'm having a problem with the link of my websites. I'm using [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) with PHP. I tried to access a page using a function by referring to it with href="controllers_name/function_name". But this happens.

This is the code of the href:

```
<li><a href="home/login">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="home/customer">Customers</a></li>
<li><a href="home/order">Orders</a></li>
<li><a href="home/product">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="home/logout" ><b>Logout</b></a></li>
```

Here's the function call:

```
function customer()
{
    $this->load->view('customer_view');
}

function order()
{
    $this->load->view('order_view');
}

function product()
{
    $this->load->view('product_view');
}

function sales()
{
    $this->load->view('sale_view');
}

function inventory()
{
    $this->load->view('inventory_view');
}

function notes()
{
    $this->load->view('notes_view');
}

function service_offered()
{
    $this->load->view('service_offered_view');
}

function about_us()
{
    $this->load->view('about_us_view');
}
```

And when I try to click the other buttons, it doesn't work (the pages are separated just like the welcome page of CodeIgniter).

Comment: Do you have your routes set?

Comment: Here's the routes


   $route['default_controller'] = "login";
  $route['404_override'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `site_url()` or `base_url()` for codeigniter to know what controller method to invoke. You're just doing `href="home/login"`, instead you have to do

```
href="<?= site_url('home/login') ?>"
```

So your html should look like the following

```
<li><a href="<?= site_url('home/login') ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="<?= site_url('home/customer') ?>">Customers</a></li>
<li><a href="<?= site_url('home/order') ?>">Orders</a></li>
<li><a href="<?= site_url('home/product') ?>">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="<?= site_url('home/logout') ?>"><b>Logout</b></a></li>
```

Hope this helps!